# Cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, null)'

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
 public void show(View view) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    pop_up dl = new pop_up();
    dl.show(manager, null);
}
```

A message has been shown: Cannot resolve method 'show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, null)'
I don't know where is the fault,
those are my imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

I tried already the solutions that I've found on the website but they didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means that it either can't find a method show() in the pop_up class, or the arguments you have provided to it don't match the method definition.

If there is a show() method in the pop_up class, check it's arguments, and make sure they match. Does the show() method use a support.v4.app.FragmentManager, or just a normal FragmentManager?

For example

```
public class pop_up {

    public void show(FragmentManager manager, ...){
        // Code
    }
}
```

If the FragmentManager argument is using support.v4.app.FragmentManager, and you don't specifically provide a support.v4.app.FragmentManager as an argument when calling the show() method, it will throw that error because it can't find a show() method with matching arguments.

Since you appear to be using a SupportFragmentManager when calling the show() method, it probably means the defined argument in the definition of the show() method in the pop_up class is ***not*** using a SupportFragmentManager.

Try changing `FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();` to `FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();`

Comment: It's weird because in my case it works with `getSupportFragmentManager()` but not with `getFragmentManager()` 

Comment: Yes, that'll be because the Fragment you're trying to work with is a support.v4.app.Fragment, and getFragmentManager() is for a simple Fragment (app.Fragment). Always check which version of Fragment you are using and use the appropriate FragmentManager.